# Handlebars template not working properly

Tags: javascript, templates, express, handlebars.js

I am testing out Handlebars templates in my express/node.js app. I wrote the following template & .js files but they are not working properly. The page displays the unordered list's 3 bullets, but does not contain the data. Does anyone know what might be going on? My console & terminal do not return any errors.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/templating.js"></script> 
</head>

<h1>Hello World</h1>
<script id="handlebars-test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <ul>
    <li>{{firstName}}</li>
    <li>{{twitter}}</li>
    <li>{{jobTitle}}</li>
    </ul>
</script>
<div id="main"></div>



$(document).ready(function() {
console.log('yo!!');
var source = $("#handlebars-test").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

var data = {
    twitter: 'fasdfasdf',
    jobTitle: 'loser',
    firstName: 'bye'
}

console.log(data);
$("#main").append(template(data));
});
```

Comment: What you've posted here appears to be able to work fine – http://jsfiddle.net/6xqthmbu/. Do you see the keys/values, `fasdfasdf`, etc., from `console.log(data);`? Is there anything else to the scripts you've written that isn't included here?

Comment: Hi - Yes, I see the correct keys/values when I console.log. There's nothing else that I added. The code is verbatim...

Comment: @TrungTran did you find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi you should call the script at the end. 
This code works fine**

```
   <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.5/handlebars.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>

    <h1>Hello World</h1>
    <script id="handlebars-test" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
        <ul>
        <li>{{firstName}}</li>
        <li>{{twitter}}</li>
        <li>{{jobTitle}}</li>
        </ul>
    </script>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
            var source = $("#handlebars-test").html();
            var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

            var data = {
                twitter: 'fasdfasdf',
                jobTitle: 'loser',
                firstName: 'bye'
            }
            var theCompiledHtml = template(data);

            // Add the compiled html to the page
            $('#main').html(theCompiledHtml);
        });  
    </script>
```